# Does the analog of homological algebra studying maps where, say, $d \circ d \circ d = 0$ have a name?

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, homological-algebra

I don't have an application in mind or anything; I'm just curious.

We can think about homological algebra as the study of endomorphisms $d$ such that $d \circ d = 0$.  Most of homological algebra seems to follow from this condition in an almost mechanical way.  Naturally this leads me to wonder exactly how specifically important the condition $d \circ d = 0$ is, rather than conditions like $d \circ d \circ d = 0$ or more generally $d^n = 0$.

Have such things been studied?  Do they have a name, or some applications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This MathOverflow thread covers the same question and has some good references](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/652/homological-algebra-and-calculus-as-in-newton).